# Обьясните по какому правилу стоит запятая?

Tags: грамматика

Было без малого восемь часов утра, когда титулярный советник Яков Петрович Голядкин очнулся после долгого сна, зевнул, потянулся и открыл наконец совершенно глаза свои.

Comment: Уточните, о какой запятой идет речь. И предложите свое решение. Домашние задания за вас мы не делаем.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

На будущее рекомендую вам указывать, какая именно запятая вас смущает.

Думаю, вероятнее всего, что речь о первой. Это сложноподчинённое предложение, соединённое союзом "когда", перед которым в сложноподчинённых предложениях ставят запятую.

Если вас действительно интересует правило, можете ознакомиться с ним у [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=137).